# Is there a reason not to use Formik as a sort of global state manager in React?

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-state-management

Found my team doing this and it feels like code smell, but I can't explain why. Formik documentation doesn't specifically address this, because why would it?

I'm working on a project with some team members that involves a complicated nested form. Imagine this grossly oversimplified example:

```
//main component
  <Formik
     
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
       const payload = {'firstName': firstName, 'lastName': lastName}
        console.log(payload); //or do whatever with the payload
      }}
    >
      <Form>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
        <Field id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Jane" />

        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <Field id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Doe" />

       <SubComponent/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  </div>
);


//SubComponent:

const {values, setFieldValue} = useFormikContext();

const handleClick = ()=> {
if (values.firstName){
setFieldValue("showAdvancedOptions", true)
}}

return (<button onClick= {handleClick}>
values.showAdvancedOptions && //render some more stuff)}
```

In other words, we're putting things that I assumed should be managed with pure React state into Formik, and using it as a state or context manager. On submit, the submit function pulls out the values of the form that are actually needed as part of the payload and constructs the payload from those, throwing away the values that were only used to track state. This strikes me as bad, but maybe it's actually good. After all, Formik's useFormikContext can be accessed at any level of the form, and ours does, sadly, have quite a few nested components.

Is there any reason *not* to use this pattern?

Comment: It kinda feels like those times when I need a hammer but I'm holding my drill. It's tempting to just whack away with a flat part of the drill, but we all know that's not really the right tool for the job. Just like I might risk damaging a good tool by not using it properly, there may be similar risks using Formik as more than it's intended. Semantically speaking it's confusing to store values that are not form fields as "form fields", you may also leak non-form values into the submit in the future because you've introduced complexity and convention that you may forget later.

Comment: This is my thinking too but I don't know that "it feels wrong" is a strong argument.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to remove opinion from the argument entirely, but it's really the same thing as intentionally misnaming a variable. Like `formValues = { ...someFormValues, ...notFormValues }` is really just as bad as something like `firstName = true`, which hopefully any dev would agree is bad. I'm also not sure it's *so* bad that'd it'd be a hill I'd die on, but I do think it's worth an attempt

Comment: Yes, I think it would be better to keep `showAdvancedOptions` in React state. If you need to make an argument, you can say doing so makes the intent clearer. When a dev sees it stored in formik, they will falsely think 'this is intended to be sent to the back end, along with the other form values'.